# Dynamically loading stylesheets, cssRules is coming up as null

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to dynamically load a stylesheet, and check whenever it's ready with cssRules property, but it's coming up as null, and I can't see why. (Chrome)

Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/PeSqR/

```
var href = "http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css";

var link = document.createElement('link');
link.setAttribute('href', href);
link.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
link.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');

var intervalId = setInterval(
    function(){
        try{
            //console.log(link.sheet);
            //console.log(link.sheet.cssRules);
            if(link.sheet && link.sheet.cssRules.length){
                clearInterval(intervalId);
                clearTimeout(timeoutId);
            }
        }
        catch(e){
            //console.log('err...' + e.message);
        }
    },
10);

var timeoutId = setTimeout(
    function(){
        clearInterval(intervalId);
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        alert('ERROR');
    },
5000);

document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is going to be to just run a null check on `link.sheet` as trying to access the `link.sheet.cssRules` property returns this error:

> [Exception... "The operation is insecure."  code: "18" nsresult: "0x80530012 (SecurityError)"  location: ""]

Try this check instead:

```
if (link.sheet != null)
```